# How coould I scale a bone to fit inside the models body?

Tags: bones, weight-painting

the bone is too wider than the models body(hand) and it is giving me a trouble while weight painting(the model shrinks). And when I try to resize/scale the bones it doesn't go as I needed it(unable to make it thiner with out affecting the length). I don't get the problem on vertical bones. only when adding horizontally the bone gets wider than needed.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot scale the default armature but if you change the bone display type to *B-Bone*, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to scale it and make it thicker or thinner. It's also fairly easy to have the default armature display type fit inside any model by scaling it down in *Edit* mode and making it longer and thinner.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reduce the thickness of bones but you can change the type of bone and choose the most suitable ones for you like this :
Go to Properties> Armature> Display> change the type of bone(Octahedral, stick, B-bone, Envelope, Wire ).

Comment: Thanks! but if the bone in the Octahedral display does not fit inside the body, changing the display to the other's does not solve the problem while painting. I am considering to increase the size of the model and to re add the bones again. But I will be looking for a better solution if exist.

Comment: @user3576 can you post a screenshot of it ?

Comment: By the way Its o.k. if a little portion of the bones stick out of your model because it is not going to be a problem. after weight painting once you finish the rigging part you won't need those bones on the viewport .

Comment: The problem arises when I make weight painting. the body just shrinks if respective bone is larger than the body.

Comment: can u give a screenshot?